# ERROR while coverity scan : No snapshot in stream has analysis summaries

Tags: java, desktop, coverity, synopsys-vcs

I am facing an issue while doing coverity scan in eclipse ..

I am scanning for this project for the first time.

It's giving me an error message

```
[ERROR] No snapshot in stream "XXXXXXXXXX" has analysis summaries
and a Code Version Date on or before 2023-04-10T15:37:00+05:30.
Review the snapshot list in Coverity Connect and enable the
"Has Analysis Summaries" column.  It may be necessary to
enable Desktop Analysis in the stream configuration and then
commit a new snapshot
```

.

Tried with new configurations,

Tried by cloning the project agaian.

Answer (score 0):

Coverity Desktop Analysis requires that a full scan of the entire code base has been previously done and the results committed to the Coverity Connect server as a snapshot (analysis results instance).  This is needed so the desktop analysis, which only looks at a subset of code, knows the behavior of the rest of the code outside that subset.  The error "No snapshot in stream ... has analysis summaries" means the required snapshot is not present on the server.

To fix this, one must perform and commit a full scan, typically using the `cov-build`, `cov-analyze`, and `cov-commit-defects` sequence of commands, although the details can vary; see the linked documentation below.  Once that is done, desktop analysis should be able to find that snapshot and retrieve its behavior summary information, resolving the error.

Relevant documentation:

- [Creating analysis summaries](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/coverity-platform/topics/creating_analysis_summaries.html): Explains the need for a snapshot with summaries and hints at how to make one.
- [Steps to generate an analysis](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/coverity-analysis/topics/steps_to_generate_an_analysis.html): Explains in detail how to perform a full analysis and commit its results.
- [Coverity Desktop Analysis: User Guide](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/webhelp-files/fast_desktop_start.html): Covers desktop analysis generally.
- [`cov-build`](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/commands/topics/cov-build.html) command line reference.
- [`cov-analyze`](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/commands/topics/cov-analyze.html) command line reference.
- [`cov-commit-defects`](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/commands/topics/cov-commit-defects.html) command line reference.
- [Troubleshooting Desktop Analysis: [ERROR] No snapshot in stream "X" has analysis summaries...](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/desktop-analysis/topics/troubleshooting_desktop_analysis.html#fast_desktop_troubleshooting__no_snapshot_in_stream): Steps to follow when encountering this error message when using `cov-run-desktop` directly.  (The advice here is potentially helpful even when using the plugin.)
- [Troubleshooting Coverity Desktop for Eclipse: [ERROR] No snapshot in stream "streamName" has analysis summaries...](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/coverity-desktop/topics-eclipse/eclipse_troubleshooting-eclipse.html#eclipse_troubleshooting__eclipse_no_analysis_summaries): Steps to follow for this error message when using the Eclipse plugin.
- [Collect Diagnostics](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs-2023.9/page/coverity-desktop/topics-cov-desktop/views_and_options_collect_diagnostics-eclipse.html): Describes how to get all of the relevant log files and other diagnostic information for the Eclipse plugin as a single `.zip` file.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the link to the documents..I went through it and i am able to build and analyse....But when trying to commit the defects to civerity server, its asking for passphrase....where can i find what is the passphrase...it's not accepting the system password..

this is the command i am trying.
cov-commit-defects --url coverity_url --stream straeam_name --dir directory_name

Comment: I'm not sure which passphrase is being requested.  Would you edit your question to include the exact command line and error message, with minimal redaction of private information?

Comment: Ok..Completed a build analyze and committed the snapshot..Now i can see that snapshot in coverity server too. But when tried to scan from Eclipse again the it failed and the error is - "Review the snapshot list in Coverity Connect and enable the
"Has Analysis Summaries" column.  It may be necessary to
enable Desktop Analysis in the stream configuration and then
commit a new snapshot."
I have checked in coverity server...Desktop Analysis is enabled already.

Comment: Would you edit your question to include a screenshot of the snapshots list in Coverity Connect (with minimal redactions)?  Additionally, I'd like to see the exact `cov-run-desktop` command line, which can be found among the files gathered by the "Collect Diagnostics" command, whose documentation I've now linked.

Comment: i have scanned and analyzed my project..But all java files are getting skipped,and this is the error i am getting

[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
For more details, please look at:
C:/Users/cov/Coverity/cov-analysis-win64-2022.6.0/bin/directory-4/build-log.txt

Comment: i have already used the cov-configure --java command.Not sure what else i need to configure so that my java files get scanned to.
i am using windows machine

Comment: Ask a separate question about emitting the java files, since that's really a separate topic (even though it's a prerequisite to what you're trying to do here).  The comments aren't a suitable place to try to resolve that.